# Im trying to set the maximum profiles in my list but i dont know how. And I don't know how to repeat # Access to create an account

Tags: python, list, loops

This line of code is confusing for me. I tried to set the list maximum amount of imputs, but i cant get it to work. In addition I dont know how to repeat the #Access to create an accout

```
# Profile List
print("How many profiles would you like on your database")
profiles = input()
while profiles < 100:
    max_profiles = []
accesAp = input('Would you like to look create a profiel (Yes or No)')

# Acces to create an account
if accesAp == 'yes':
    username = input('\nWhat do you want your username to be?')
    profiles.append(username.strip())
    print('\nHello ' + username.title())
    proIdLook = input('\nWould you like to look up your ID ' + username.title() + (' (Yes or No)'))
    if proIdLook == 'yes':
        print("\n" + username.title() + ' = ', str(username.index(username)))
signOut = input("\nNow that you've created an account, would you like to sign out.")
if input == 'yes':
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a counter that will count every profile created.

```
 print("How many profiles would you like on your database")
 profiles = input()
 counter = 0
 while counter < 100:
    max_profiles = []
    counter+=1
    accesAp = input('Would you like to look create a profiel (Yes or No)')
```